# Getting a typeerror in firebug after using .content().get().nodevalue;

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get a number out of each and every html LI
inside the LI there are links as shown in below html code:

```
<div id="summary">
        <ul class="nobullets last-child">
           <li><a href="#">Blog Posts</a> (9)</li>
           <li><a href="#">Photos</a> </li>
           <li><a href="#">Discussion</a> (10)</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see there are numbers beside some of the links inside each of the LIs
I want to get only those that have numbers (the blog posts) then store that number into a variable, if they dont have numbers it will just put a 0 into the variable.

But here's my jquery code:

```
var getblog;
var getphoto;
      //blogs
      if($('#summary').find('ul li:first-child').contents().get(1).nodeValue != 'undefined'){
        getblog = $('#summary').find('ul li:first-child').contents().get(1).nodeValue;
        getblog = parseFloat( getblog.substr(2) );

      }
      else{
        getblog = '0';
      }


      //photos
      //+ li to get the second child
      if($('#summary').find('ul li:first-child + li').contents().get(1).nodeValue != 'undefined'){

        getphoto = $('#summary').find('ul li:first-child + li').contents().get(1).nodeValue;
        getphoto = parseFloat( getphoto.substr(2) );
      }
      else{
         getphoto = '0';
      }
```

firebug is throwing me with an error:
**TypeError: $("#summary").next().find("ul li:first-child + li").contents().get(1) is undefined**

Here's the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hP3Wq/

the blog is showing 9 which works but the **photos is showing NaN instead of 0**

Comment: `If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat() returns NaN.` photos has no numbers, so it will always return NaN.

Comment: Your code is weird; you're getting the HTML contents of something - which will be a string value - and then you're checking "nodeValue" on the string.  When will that not be `undefined`?  Strings don't have a "nodeValue" property.

Comment: it supposed to be .contents().get(1) not .html() , just forgot to change it back.

Comment: Ah, I see - you're comparing that real `undefined` value to the **string** "undefined", so that test will always succeed.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after (you want only `li`s with numbers, and at the same time if it doesn't have a number you want zero?), but it can be much simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/hP3Wq/2/.

Comment: yes thats it pimvdb , you should post this as the answer i will select it as the answer , thanksss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is all trying to accomplish, but if it's just matching e.g. the `(3)` prefix that's possibly apparent, you can just use `.text()` and `.match()` as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/hP3Wq/2/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // use a generic function so as not to repeat things
    var getNumber = function(index) {
        return ($("#summary li")  // from the lis
                .eq(index)        // a specific li from the lis
                .contents()       // its contents
                .last()           // number is apparent in the last text node
                .text()           // its text
                // match it against a regexp defining "(somenumbers)";
                // in case of no match, use a dummy array with zeroes
                // (this defines the fallback)
                .match(/\((\d*)\)/) || [0, 0]
               )[1];
    };
    var getblog = getNumber(0);
    var getphoto = getNumber(1);

    $('#summary').after(getblog + '<br>' + getphoto);
});
```